# How can Redirect URL special characters with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, character

How can Redirect URL special characters with HTACCESS.
This URL seems very confusing and long, I want to add redirects to it, but I am not knowledgeable about HTACCESS. Thank you !

```
Orginal: https://my-site.com/index.php?language=en&nv=faq&op=you-can-dance-on-moon
Redirct to: https://my-site.com/faq/you-can-dance-on-moon/
```

I tried to try this code - but the server has no reaction:
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/faq=(.*)$ index.php?language=$1&nv=faq&op=$2 [R=301,L]

After that, I tried it again with another format, the result was still unable to redirect this URL:
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/faq=(.*)$ index.php?language=$1&nv=faq&op=$2 [L]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only. If you want to match on query string contents, you need to do that with a RewriteCond - for details, see linked duplicate, please, and do some additional research if you need more info/details.

Comment: Plus, is this only the "reverse" direction of this, you'd use this to fix "old" links that are already out there in the wild. On your own site, you should see to it that those links are output as `/faq/you-can-dance-on-moon/` to begin with. And then you need a rule, that internally rewrites that to your URL with those parameters, so that your PHP script behind this knows what to do.